# The variable \partname is not included in the CONTENTS output display in amsbook class

Tags: formatting, titlesec, books, titletoc

```
%
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ %
\documentclass[english,11pt]{book}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ %
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath} %
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec} %
\usepackage{titletoc} %
\usepackage{hhline} %
\usepackage[paperwidth=170mm,paperheight=240mm,textwidth=132mm,top=8mm,bottom=8mm,lmargin=12.5mm,rmargin=12.5mm,
bindingoffset=12.5mm,noheadfoot,nomarginpar,showframe,showcrop]{geometry}
\usepackage[a4,frame,cam,center]{crop} %
\usepackage{hyperref} %

%\titleformat{\part}[display] % for DISPLAY DISPLAY
%{\filcenter \color{black}\itshape\fontsize{15}{18}\selectfont} %
%{\hrule\vspace*{6pt}\\ \color{black}\bfseries\normalfont\fontsize{15}{18}\selectfont{A series of books}} %
%{8pt}
%{\filcenter\partname\hspace{3.2pt}\Roman{part} \hspace{1.8pt}- \hspace{1.0pt}{#1}\\[2pt]\hrule} %

\titlespacing*{\part}{0pt}{132pt}{20pt}[0pt]

\titleformat{\chapter}[display] % for DISPLAY DISPLAY
{\color{blue}\bfseries\itshape\fontsize{12}{15}\selectfont} %
{\color{black}\hspace{30pt}\chaptername\hspace{3.2pt}\normalfont\fontsize{12}{15}\selectfont{\thechapter}} %
{0pt}
{\bfseries\normalfont\fontsize{15}{18}\selectfont{\hspace{21pt}{#1}}} %

\renewcommand{\thepart}{\arabic{part}}

\titlecontents{part}[0em] % for TOC TOC TOC ****************************************************************
        {\addvspace{15pt}}
        {\textbf{\partname\hspace{4.2pt}\thecontentslabel}} % \partname NOT displayed in contents output on p3 **************
        {}
        {\titlerule*[18pt]{.}\contentspage\;}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\part{first part}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{The first chapter of part 1} % start of chapter ONE

\part{second part} % start of new part

\chapter{The first chapter of part 2} % start of chapter ONE

\end{document}
```

Comment: If I run your code I get `Runaway argument?
{\bfseries \normalfont \fontsize {15}{18}\selectfont {\hspace {21pt}{\ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \ttl@format@ii was complete.`  as there is is a missing `}`

Comment: adding the missing `} gives `! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.` due to the mis placed `\\ ` after any error the PDF output (if any) is arbitrary so it's not surprising if the table of contents does not have the expected text

Comment: @David Carlise Thank you, David...  I've commented out the whole section headed "\titleformat{\part}[display]" and this cleared the errors; the problem still persists.

Comment: please update the code here so people have something to test.

Comment: Code updated as requested.

Comment: how is this related to the `math-mode` tag?

Comment: I thought there might be an a connection with the amsmath package.

Comment: `amsmath` does not iinteract with headers in any way. I'd suggest removing that tag such that people tracing the tack does not need to look at your question as it is not related.

Comment: @daleif cannot see a way to remove the tag.

Comment: @campa I wish to accept your answer as it did answer the question posed - but it has disappeared.